# Why is Gmail “is:unread and label:random” not returning unread emails with label “random”?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

`label:random` shows a bunch of emails with three unread. But when I search for `label:random and label:unread`, no results are returned.

When I only search for `label:unread`, or `is:read`, all unread emails are returned, including the three that have `label:random`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple. The `and` was creating problems. It was supposed to be capital.

All of these worked:

```
is:unread in:random
is:unread AND label:random
label:unread label:random
label:unread AND label:random
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `is:unread` and not `in:unread`.

Refer to [this support page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) for more search operators.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work too. Also 'label:unread and label:random' doesn't work either. And if you look at my post, I don't think I have put in 'in:unread'

Comment: In fact it's in the title of your post.